# Font size different in PSD and live site

Tags: .net, psd

I have done a .aspx site.I have provided the same font size and same font family,but it is not   match like the psd image. Is there any problem or cause for the issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web site and your Photoshop mockup use different resolutions. I think browsers commonly use 96 dpi whereas Photoshop probably defaulteed to 72 dpi.

Another point is that Photoshop and the browser likely disagree on the exact rendering of text. Photoshop is for making raster images for a variety of purposes whereas a browser only has to concern itself with on-screen display. This means that antialiasing and pixel-grid fitting likely differ.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your browser doesn't support the font you are using?